# how to set property maxConnection in cxf cilent code

Tags: connection, cxf, httpurlconnection, httpconnection, cxf-client

I am developing cxf client. I generate stub from  wsdl and develope code from there. My code is something like that

```
URL WSDL_LOCATION = new URL(targetURL);
CustomerWS_Service CustomerWSService = new CustomerWS_Service (WSDL_LOCATION);
CustomerWS customerWS = CustomerWSService.getCustomerWSPort();
```

Now, i want to set some property to the connection:

```
max_total_connection: maximum number of connections allowed
max_connection_per_host: maximum number of connections allowed for a given host config
```

Some research tell me to set those properties in HttpUrlConnection. But i dont know how to do that Or atleast how to have HttpUrlConnection obj from the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set this at Bus level. Bus properties can be configured as like below. You are not using async so don't need to put this property.
Also I would recommend to create client from `JaxWsClientFactoryBean`

`SpringBus bus = new SpringBus();
        bus.setProperty(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC, Boolean.TRUE);
 bus.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.SO_KEEPALIVE",Boolean.TRUE);        bus.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.SO_TIMEOUT",Boolean.FALSE); bus.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.MAX_CONNECTIONS","totalConnections"));
bus.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.MAX_PER_HOST_CONNECTIONS","connectionsPerHost"));`

Comment: Thanks. But i dont use async. Your sample is for async only. Does it work with sync call?

Comment: Yes It works for sync as well just don't set that to false.

Comment: Thanks again. You say "just don't set that to false". Do you mean bus.setProperty(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC, Boolean.TRUE);

Comment: Oh My Bad I meant set it to false.`bus.setProperty(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC, Boolean.FALSE);` Basically CXF gives preference to async but at the same time it takes the configuration for sync client also in the same way.